# How to handle activities stack?

Tags: android, listview, android-activity, stack

I have 4 activities. Two of them are for login/registration. After successful login, user moves to activity rooms where user can select room to chat in. Then he can press back and select another room to chat in two/multiple rooms. Now i dont want to finish chat activity. When user press back(twice) at room activity whole app should finish.

But rather than finishing it launches chat activity throwing error because it has lost its data. Now how can i accomplish that.
Chat activity is launched from customadapter and it launches room activity on backpress using flag reorder to front.

**Update:**

I DO NOT WANT TO FINISH MY CHAT ACTIVITY ON BACK PRESS. I KNOW HOW FINISH() WORKS. I WANT TO CLEAR STACK AND EXIT ON BACKPRESS OF ROOM ACTIVITY.

**Suggestion:**
Don't teach me how to finish activity just by calling finish or how to exit on double backtap. If you don't have sufficent knowledge about flags then there is no need to load StackOverflow with junk.

Comment: _" I want to clear stack and exit on backpress of room activity."_ So call [`finishAffinity`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#finishAffinity()).

Comment: If people are mis-interpreting your question, perhaps you should simplify your explanation about what you're trying to achieve. Instead of pouting that no one is understanding.

Comment: finishAffinity is what i was looking for. Please add it as answer so i can accept it.

Answer (score 0):

try like this :

```
boolean doubleBackToExitPressedOnce = false;

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (doubleBackToExitPressedOnce) {
        super.onBackPressed();
        return;
    }

this.doubleBackToExitPressedOnce = true;
Toast.makeText(this, "Please click BACK again to exit", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        doubleBackToExitPressedOnce=false;                       
    }
}, 2000);
```

}

Comment: This question is about activities stack not about how to exit app on double backtap. I already have done that.

Comment: use Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP to clear previous activities.. Also this is helpful to check that user back two time to exit.. So for first back press clear activity stack and in second time close application

Comment: Flags are of no use until we do some action like start activity from flagged intent.

Comment: If you use finish when move from one activity to other then there is no need to clear stack

Comment: That way i wont b able to switch faster between two activities.

Comment: finish doesn't effect for intent speed

Comment: Then i wonder why flags are there? What you are saying is that there is no difference between loading activity once OR loading it multiple times. Remmember if i dont finish activity , it dont have to start from scratch like populating layout and data in it. Only OnResume is called.

Comment: i think your question needs negative... You first read android developer tutorials

Answer (score 0):

You should try to clear the activity stack for that particular task. So do this before firing '`startActivity`

`yourIntent.setFlag(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)`

Comment: In room activity or chat activity.

Answer (score 0):

You might not finishing your activity so it is called again on back press so finish the previous activity before starting chat room activity by calling finish() method.

and if you want to finish application on press back(twice) then you should manage counter on onBackPressed() method in chat room activity.